# Change the value of dynamically created input fields using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please view the following jsfiddle;

https://jsfiddle.net/1kvwxmyb/3/

Basically, the code allows the user to add 'lines' to an invoice. When the user selects the 'VAT Rate' of a product, I need the 'VAT Amount' and 'Gross Amount' to be calculated using jQuery. Calculating these figures is basic maths but at present I can't even get the jQuery to set any type of value in 'VAT Amount' and 'Gross Amount' never mind the correct figure!

Please help.

jQuery

```
// calculate VAT amount and set gross amount

$(".vat_rate").change(function () {

    alert("Handler for .change() called.");

    $(this).nextAll('input').first().val("123");

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, to start off, change the code in question to the following.

```
// calculate VAT amount and set gross amount
$(".nobord").on("change", ".vat_rate", function () {

    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");

    var $qty = $row.find("input[name^='invoice_line_quantity']");
    var $amount = $row.find("input[name^='invoice_line_amount']");
    //Value of the Qty input
    console.log($qty.val());
    //Value of the Net Amount input
    console.log($amount.val());

    //Now do your math and set the value as below

    $row.find("input[name^='invoice_line_vat_amount']").val("your_value");
    $row.find("input[name^='invoice_line_gross_amount']").val("your_value");
});
```

And your HTML was a bit messed up as the order of closing the TD/TR wasn't right. Take a look at the corrections I have made [on this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1kvwxmyb/6/).

Hope that's a good start :)

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1kvwxmyb/9/

Just added `true` parameter to `clone` function, which causes clone element with an event handler.

Citation from jQuery documentation

> .clone( [withDataAndEvents ] )
>
> withDataAndEvents (default: false)
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> A Boolean indicating whether event handlers should be copied along with the elements. As of jQuery 1.4, element data will be copied as well.

and I also add sample calculation to `change` function.

To get row where option was changed `var $row = $(this).closest("tr");` and then you can find input with `$row.find("input[name^='invoice_line_vat_amount']")`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, now it's works for new lines https://jsfiddle.net/1kvwxmyb/11/

js

```
    $(document).on('change', '.vat_rate',function () {

        var row = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");

        var qty = $("#" + row + " td:nth-child(1) input");
        var desc = $("#" + row + " td:nth-child(2) input");
        var netam = $("#" + row + " td:nth-child(3) input");
        var vatam = $("#" + row + " td:nth-child(5) input");
        var grossam = $("#" + row + " td:nth-child(6) input");

        vatam.val("123");

        //alert("Handler for .change() called.");

        //$(this).nextAll('input').first().val("123");

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

One little change

```
// calculate VAT amount and set gross amount

$(".vat_rate").change(function (event) {

    $(event.target).parent().parent().find('td:nth-child(3) input').val('0.5');

});
```